# Mixed experimental design with between and within interaction terms using lme4 in R

Tags: r, lme4

I have a question about the following experiment:
I have two groups of people (6 emergency docs and 6 gastroenterologists). They all receive the same treatment. I want to see whether the increase in performance (i.e., `diag_diff_ge_post`) is higher among the emergency docs compared to the gastroenterologists (this idea is reflected in the `group*time` term).
Performance is measured before and after the treatment. The performance is measured using participants' diagnostic ratings for 3 emergency cases (every participant receives all 3 cases for rating) and each case is of different quality (so some cases describe the diagnosis more detailed than others).
In my understanding, this means there is a nested data structure. I account for this with the `quality|id` term. Now I also believe there is an interaction between the case quality and the group: With increasing case quality, the increase in performance will be higher among emergency physicians when compared to gastroenterology consultants (this is reflected in the `group*quality` term).
I am not sure whether my model specification is correct because case qualities are nested in individuals? Could you maybe help me here?

Here is my dataframe:

```
library(lme4)
data_ex <- structure(list(diag_diff_ge_pre = c(0.26, 0.26, 2.75, 2.75, 1.47, 
1.47, -1.41, -1.41, -1.92, -1.92, 1.57, 1.57, 0.7, 0.7, 0.56, 
0.56, 0.33, 0.33, 3.19, 3.19, -2.76, -2.76, 1.7, 1.7, -1.47, 
-1.47, 2.37, 2.37, 0.88, 0.88, 2.58, 2.58, 0.51, 0.51, -1.08, 
-1.08), diag_diff_ge_post = c(-0.87, -0.87, -0.81, -0.81, -1.67, 
-1.67, 0.54, 0.54, -1.41, -1.41, -1.42, -1.42, 0.73, 0.73, 1.03, 
1.03, -0.4, -0.4, -0.3, -0.3, 0.86, 0.86, -0.43, -0.43, 0.35, 
0.35, -0.98, -0.98, 1.31, 1.31, 0.96, 0.96, 2.92, 2.92, -0.91, 
-0.91), id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
    case = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3), quality = c(11.06, 11.06, 11.06, 11.06, 11.06, 11.06, 
    9.08, 9.08, 9.08, 9.08, 9.08, 9.08, 6.33, 6.33, 6.33, 6.33, 
    6.33, 6.33, 11.06, 11.06, 11.06, 11.06, 11.06, 11.06, 9.08, 
    9.08, 9.08, 9.08, 9.08, 9.08, 6.33, 6.33, 6.33, 6.33, 6.33, 
    6.33), age = c(50, 24, 45, 26, 21, 86, 50, 24, 45, 26, 21, 
    86, 50, 24, 45, 26, 21, 86, 50, 24, 45, 26, 21, 86, 50, 24, 
    45, 26, 21, 86, 50, 24, 45, 26, 21, 86), experience = c(50, 
    24, 45, 26, 21, 86, 50, 24, 45, 26, 21, 86, 50, 24, 45, 26, 
    21, 86, 50, 24, 45, 26, 21, 86, 50, 24, 45, 26, 21, 86, 50, 
    24, 45, 26, 21, 86), autonomy = c(1.62, 2.27, 3.58, 3.56, 
    2.77, 3.17, 1.62, 2.27, 3.58, 3.56, 2.77, 3.17, 1.62, 2.27, 
    3.58, 3.56, 2.77, 3.17, 1.62, 2.27, 3.58, 3.56, 2.77, 3.17, 
    1.62, 2.27, 3.58, 3.56, 2.77, 3.17, 1.62, 2.27, 3.58, 3.56, 
    2.77, 3.17), know_exp = c(3.91, 4, 2.94, 1.18, 1.88, 3.26, 
    3.91, 4, 2.94, 1.18, 1.88, 3.26, 3.91, 4, 2.94, 1.18, 1.88, 
    3.26, 3.91, 4, 2.94, 1.18, 1.88, 3.26, 3.91, 4, 2.94, 1.18, 
    1.88, 3.26, 3.91, 4, 2.94, 1.18, 1.88, 3.26), attitude = c(2.14, 
    2.81, 5.31, 2.07, 2.67, 4.73, 2.14, 2.81, 5.31, 2.07, 2.67, 
    4.73, 2.14, 2.81, 5.31, 2.07, 2.67, 4.73, 2.14, 2.81, 5.31, 
    2.07, 2.67, 4.73, 2.14, 2.81, 5.31, 2.07, 2.67, 4.73, 2.14, 
    2.81, 5.31, 2.07, 2.67, 4.73), group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("gastro", "emergency"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("1", 
"1.1", "2", "2.1", "3", "3.1", "4", "4.1", "5", "5.1", "6", "6.1", 
"7", "7.1", "8", "8.1", "9", "9.1", "10", "10.1", "11", "11.1", 
"12", "12.1", "13", "13.1", "14", "14.1", "15", "15.1", "16", 
"16.1", "17", "17.1", "18", "18.1"), class = "data.frame")
```

And this is the model:

```
library(lme4)
model <- lme4::lmer(diag_diff_ge_post ~ diag_diff_ge_pre + group*time + 
                experience + autonomy + know_exp + attitude + group*quality + 
                (quality|id), data=data_ex)
model
```

Comment: where is your `group` variable ... ?

Comment: I think that would be `id`? So the quality of the cases (`quality`) is nested in `id`. That is, each person receives each of the three cases of different qualities.

Comment: What I mean is that your formula has `group` in it, but there's no `group` variable in the data sample you posted ...

Comment: Oh, sorry! I just edited the dataframe and added the group variable. Thanks for the question!

Answer (score 0):

"In my understanding, this means there is a nested data structure. I account for this with the `quality|id` term."

Firstly, nesting is done with the slash symbol `/`, and the `|` is for defining random effects.

So you need to work out if you have that specific type of random effect first, or if you are trying to nest them like this `(1|quality/id)`

Whether that defines your model correctly, I cannot tell, I am just correcting your understanding of the formula syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this issue out to me. I looked into the package manual and explanations how to specify multilevel models with lme4. I believe that this is the correct model: 

```model <- lme4::lmer(diag_like_em_post ~ experience + autonomy + know_exp + attitude + quality*group + (1|quality) + (1|group/id), data=data)```

= random intercepts for quality (ID and quality are crossed), and ID is nested in the two groups.

Comment: If you still have questions on the experimental design, you might get more attention on Cross Validated https://stats.stackexchange.com because it is more stats oriented, whereas StackOverflow is more specifically code problem oriented. If my code solution helped fix the overall problem please consider an upvote. Cheers.